# Space requirement for dancing game

Tags: xbox-360, kinect, dance-central-2, just-dance-3

I recently bought an Xbox 360 with Kinect and now my girlfriend really wants one of the dancing games (e.g. Just Dance 3 or Dance Central 2).
I'ld be happy to buy her one of those games but my concern is whether or not she will be able to play it.
My Kinect sensor is only able to see the top half of the body so I'm not sure if she can actually play it. Does the dancing games for the Kinect track the movements of the legs?

Comment: I don't have a Kinect Sensor, but [their support site](http://www.dancecentral.com/support#settingup) seems to indicate you need to see your whole body.

Comment: @DoozerBlake I was looking for that but couldn't find it. They seem to have a good support site which answers all of those questions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My wife has Dance Central for the Kinect, and it does track your entire body.  Leg movements are involved in practically every dance routine.  For us, the couch is around 6' from the TV in the Xbox 360 room, and we have to push it back about another 2-3' in order for her to have enough room to dance.

As a more "real world" test, if you have Kinect Adventures, (which is likely since it's typically the pack-in title for the Kinect) and the game complains that you're not far enough away for "2 player play," you probably don't have enough room.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Great idea trying Kinect Adventures. I'll see if it complains. If it does, I will try to move the couch. I was just wondering if it would track the legs, if it didn't I would certainly have enough space.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from videos I've watched, and seeing that it tracks movements of arms and legs, and the below part directly from Dance Central's [support site](http://www.dancecentral.com/support#settingup), I would say that Dance Central requires your whole body to be visible.

> **How far should I stand back from the Kinect sensor?**
>
> Get noticed! Don’t
> stand too close to the sensor, or too far away. 6 feet is ideal. Once
> you’re visible from head to toe in the helper frame, you’re good to
> go.

**Disclaimer:** I haven't played Dance Central, nor do I have a Kinect.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your Kinect sensor on top of your TV, then the Kinect will automatically move to adjust. The far you are the better, but not too far.